# When inserting a record, Wordpress automatically set non set variable to 0

Tags: mysql, wordpress, php-7.2

I have this php snippet:

```
$sql = "
    CREATE TABLE $tablename (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        code varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        created_by mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
        updated_by mediumint(9) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;
";

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

And later, later on I'm running this:

```
$wpdb->insert($tablename, ['code' => 'test', 'name' => 'Test'], ['%s','%s']);
```

What should lead to the MySQL exception saying 'created_by cannot be null', but except this it is set to 0.

---

I tried manual insert:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`code`, `name`) VALUES ('test_list2', 'Test List 2')
```

And I got expected exception.

---

I also tried to put trigger before insert to be sure, that change went from the Wordpress:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_my_table
    BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.created_by IS NULL THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'created_by column has to be set to current user id and not null';
        ELSEIF NEW.created_by = 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'created_by column has to be set to current user id and not 0';
        END IF;
    END$$
```

BUT that trigger return message: 'created_by column has to be set to current user id and not null'.

---

Knows anybody what's going on?

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but why don't you just set the `created_by` ID in your insert statement?

Comment: `INSERT INTO `my_table` (`code`, `name`, `created_by`) VALUES ('test_list2', 'Test List 2', get_current_user_id())`

Comment: Wpdb class throws no exception. Try to check $wpdb->last_error after insert.

Comment: I'll check the $wpdb->last_error as soon as I will be able, thanks for this tip KAGG. I understand that some developers just will use the solution what Jamie_D pointing on, but point of my approach is to be sure how the WP works with the database, know own data and be consistent, as 0 != null. In general if you want to abstract functionality and send responsibility to objects in the higher oop hierarchy, you must be sure what are you doing to avoid to use multiple if's statements in the code. But this is my opinion, nothing wrong what you wrote :).

Comment: I solved the problem by making the created_by as a foreign key, but behaviour what I described seems to me wrong, so I raised this topic.